# Win 10 not allowing broadband usb modem internet access

Tags: usb, modem, broadband

I have a Sierra Wireless 313u broadband USB modem. It is logged onto ATT broadband. But, Windows 10 reports no internet. This is an old issue with many others having same problem.
Is this a USB issue? A modern issue? Driver issue?

Is there a solution?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for trying. It is a Windows problem since 2016. ATT sees the USB modem in their system. Windows KNOWS it is in the PC computer. BUT, Windows does not process the broadband connection. No Internet. The closest I have gotten results in a DNS error. Yet, previous Windows versions did it automatically. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is very likely a compatibility issue. Drivers exist for Windows 7 and older.

> OS SUPPORT (DRIVERS AND SDK) Windows® 7, Vista®, or XP Service Pack 3
> (32 and 64 bit

[Sierra Data Sheet](https://file:///C:/Users/jdhurst/AppData/Local/Temp/MicrosoftEdgeDownloads/8130bcda-c021-43a1-86d1-5eda276cc301/sierra_aircard_313u_datasheet.pdf)

Note: I have not seen Sierra for some time. I have an old one somewhere. I used Nokia for 7 8 and early 10.  I now use Huawei for 10 and 11. You likely need a new card.

Answer (score 0):

NETGEAR Support in the article
[How do I check if my product is compatible with Windows 10](https://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/29490#win10_aircard)
says this:

> These products are compatible with Windows 10 when using Watcher B4093
> and above. If your device is running on a lower version, visit
> [Watcher
> B4093](http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/aircard/AC340U/Watcher_Generic_UM.msi?cid=gwmng)
> and download Watcher B4093:
>
> - AirCard 340U - Generic / Telus
> - AirCard 330U
> - AirCard 320U
> - **AirCard 313U**, 318U, 319U